# Problem with 'stat_compare_means' when using the 'facet_wrap' function

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to create a faceted plot like below. However, stats always  only get applied to one of the plots. Is there a workaround keeping the figure appearance the same, but adding stats to both?

Here is the code that I am using

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=`Treatment`,y=`Endostatin`, fill=Treatment))+

geom_boxplot(outlier.alpha = 0.25, outlier.color = "red") +

geom_point(alpha = 0.25, size = 2 ) +

facet_wrap(~Mode, scale="free") +

stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons) +

theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20))
```

[image: Output plot_edited]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `stat_compare_means` separately

```
my_comparisons1 <- list(c("SHAM+vehicle", "TAC+vehicle"), c("TAC+vehicle", "TAC+relaxin"), c("TAC_vehicle", "TAC+Enalapril"))
my_comparisons2 <- list(c("TAC+vehicle", "TAC+relaxin")

stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons1 ) +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons2 )
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, with the 'scale="free" option, multiple 'stat_compare_means' do not work as expected.